# how to use jquery on asp.net button and by using that i want to perform show() on apanel..and perform some server side code

Tags: asp.net

I am doing a project in asp.net. i have a panel which contains some field like txtbox ,buttons etc..I want to use jquery event on a asp.net button click which will open this panel by using jquery show() function and also perform some tasks in server side. Please help me.

The code is :

```
protected void btninsertfordeo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       // GridViewforcontact.Enabled = false;
        PanelForInsert.Visible = true;
        colvisible = true;
        txtfaxnoextra.Focus();
        if (colvisible == true)
        {
            GridViewforcontact.Columns[9].Visible = false;
        }
        colvisible = false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OnClientClick property of the button to call your client-side function and OnClick to call your server code

```
<asp:Button ID="btninsertfordeo" runat="server" OnClientClick="functionToShowPanel()" OnClick="hlkContinue_Click" Text="Click"></asp:Button>

<script>
functionToShowPanel(){
    $('#pnlToShow').show()
}
</script>
```

or without using OnClientClient you can probably do:

```
$('#<%=btninsertfordeo.ClientID %>').click(function(){
    $('#pnlToShow').show()
}
```

Another option would be to use an UpdatePanel instead of jquery to show/hide elements on the page. This way you can control the visibility of your div from your code-behind. Add all the dynamic elements within the UpdatePanel's ContentTemplate and add your button as an AsynPostbackTrigger for the UpdatePanel to enable dynamic updating of our page.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btninsertfordeo" EventName="click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="PanelForInsert" runat="server" Visible="false">
            //Your textboxes, buttons etc goes here
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Button ID="btninsertfordeo" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="btninsertfordeo_Click"></asp:Button>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here are links to documentation that will help you in understanding and implementing an UpdatePanel:

[Introduction to the UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx)

[UpdatePanel Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[UpdatePanel Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: SIR,I HAVE TRIED THIS..ONCLIENTCLICK NOT WORKING ONLY SERVER SIDE CODE EXECUTED...

Comment: I'm assuming that the button click event does a postback which makes it seem like the client side code isn't executing. I've updated my answer with an example of how to implement an update panel.

Comment: when i try to insert trigger i got below warning.....

Element 'AsyncPostBackTrigger' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing.

client side code not executing....**

Comment: It's possible that there's an error in your aspx code or ajax in your project. I've added some links to my answer where you can get a better understanding on how to use the UpdatePanel